# PHP SOAP - Ignore Mandatory Schema Variables

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

Is there a way to ignore mandatory variables in a schema with the PHP soap client using WSDL mode?

We've developed an application that communicates with a SOAP endpoint that has been working for 7+ years. Recently the SOAP endpoint provider has upgraded their API and provided us with a new endpoint and WSDL.

For a particular call their documentation suggest that several variables are optional, however the schema referred to in their WSDL state that these variables are not optional.

Whilst you can use SOAPUI (which ignores the schema) to send some XML without these variables and it works, when you try and form an object to pass to the PHP soap client without these variables it refuses and throws an exception saying they are mandatory.

The endpoint provider is refusing to update their Schema, and we don't seem to have a way to make a call using the PHP soap client.

Comment: Have you tried updating the schema your own?

Answer (score 1):

Host your own WSDL file.

You can save the WSDL of the service locally, make the changes you need to it, and have the PHP SOAP client use this WSDL when making calls to the original web service.

If the web service accepts calls with fewer parameters, then this is a way to bypass mandatory parameters in the WSDL.

Do note though, that this might be just temporary. It seems they made the contract of the web service more restrictive, but they have not made changes to the service implementation. This might be done at some point. If they do, then the service itself will enforce the parameters, and you won't be able to work your way around that. At that point you need to send everything the service expects.

Comment: Whilst it doesn't really answer the question, i.e. is there a way of ignoring the mandatory fields, it is a useful suggestion. Thank you.